# How to create man-pages and link them like in vim help system?

Tags: help-system

I would like to create documentation just like vim-help system . Multiple .txt files with links and cross references and where I can jump foreward  `CTRL+]` and back using `CTRL+T`. How is it done?

Comment: check `:h help-writing`

Comment: Seems like linking is maintained using `tags`.